# Authentic Testing of Mobile Website

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, mobile, android

I'm currently on a project in which we've set up a test infrastructure for automated regression testing of the customer's website (that is, the desktop and mobile versions thereof).

My question concerns the mobile site: What we're doing at the moment is using Behat with the Mink API in order to talk to Selenium Grid on different virtual machines (for parallelization). On these machines we're running Firefox browsers with a modified profiles that "fakes" being a different user agent (e.g. an android mobile browser). We then execute automated test cases on the delivered mobile version of the page.

What I'm now trying to accomplish is to make these tests more authentic since we've observed that the (destop) browser we use can behave quite different from the actual built-in mobile browsers in use in the real world.

The best thing would be to be able to actually control an emulator or a real device even (we got some in stock) through the Selenium Grid.

Unfortunately, I don't have any idea where to start on this since I have few to no prior experience with the testing of "real" mobile web applications.

So here's my question: Does anyone of you have a good tip for me where to start or what to look for? I'd be very thankful for any kind of guidance on how o go about this ...

Yours,
Gabriel

Answer (score 1):

You can try appium, https://github.com/appium/appium I believe there is some support for web testing however it may not be stable at the moment.

Another option would be to try a service like https://www.browserstack.com/automate

Comment: Hi, I've tried setting up Appium in my environment for some time now - but did not succeed. Do you know a good tutorial / documenation on appium (other than the official doc) that explains how to set up and use it through a php-binding?

Answer (score 0):

Googling for 5 seconds found http://selendroid.io/ - selenium driver for android. Does it help? What else you need?

Comment: Hi, my problem with this tool is that it appears to only work with Java. As I mentioned above we're using Behat/Mink, that is, we're working with PHP. Do you know any way to make use of Selendroid in our setting?

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use PHP you're stuck with using the PHPUnit implementation of the bindings. Unfortunately I'm not aware of any BDD PHP framework that supports mobile devices.

Information about php-client can be found at https://github.com/appium/php-client .